# How to calculate distance formula in fx-991MS calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, calculator

For formula $X=\sqrt{(A-B)^2 + (C-D)^2}$, how do I store this formula and take the values for A,B,C,D to get the value for X quickly without wasting time to write again the whole thing.

Comment: the fx-991? could you provide a link? anyway, have you checked the manual for how to program your calculator?

Answer (score 1):

[Using CALC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlSOm.png)

You may use CALC function, as suggested in this picture extracted from the manual.

Make sure you set the mode to COMP or CMPLX before calculating